# Problema al rotar pantalla android : InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android

Tengo una actividad y dos fragmentos y al rotar la pantalla del dispositivo aparece el error de que `"Unable to start activity"`. Indica que el problema está en la línea de la actividad donde se pone `setContentView(R.layout.fragments`); en la actividad. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Fragmento1:

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

    private Callbacks mCallback = null;

    public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
        Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
        return fragment;
    }
    public Fragment1(){
}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.principal,
                    container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            mCallback = (Callbacks) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement Callbacks");
        }
    }

    public interface Callbacks {
            public void onBoton1Selected (View v);

            public void onBoton2Selected (View v);

    }
    }
```

En el fragmento2:

```
        public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
        private static String boton="";


        public  View rootView = null;

        public static Fragment2 newInstance(String botonSelected) {
        Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("BOTON", botonSelected);
        boton=botonSelected;

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                boton = savedInstanceState.getString("BOTON");
            }
                if(boton.compareTo("boton1")==0) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boton1,
                    container, false);
        }else{
            if(boton.compareTo("boton2")==0) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boton2,
                        container, false);
            }else{
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vacio,
                        container, false);
            }
        }
            return rootView;
        }
public Fragment2(){
}
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString("BOTON", boton);

    }

    }
```

En la actividad:

```
 public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements     Fragment1.Callbacks {

private boolean doble = false;
private String boton="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            boton = savedInstanceState.getString("BOTON");


   }

        setContentView(R.layout.fragments);

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment2_container) != null)
        doble = true;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void onBoton1Selected(View v) {

    if (doble == false) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BOTON","boton1");
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }

    Fragment2 fragment=Fragment2.newInstance("boton1");
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag2, fragment).commit();

}
public void onBoton2Selected(View v) {

    if (doble == false) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);

        intent.putExtra("BOTON","boton2");
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }

    Fragment2 fragment=Fragment2.newInstance("boton2");
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag2, fragment).commit();
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("BOTON", boton);

}

}
```

LogCat del error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
 ComponentInfo{es.user.prueba/es.user.Principal}:   
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22:
 Error inflating class fragment

 at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)


at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

   at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)

 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)

 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment

   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)

 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)

 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)

 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)

   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)

  at es.user.Principal.onCreate(Principal.java:20)

  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 

 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832) 

 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117) 

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935) 

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 

  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 

   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 

     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 

 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment es.user.Fragment1 did not create a view.

    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2314)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)

   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)

  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityDonut.java:44)

 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:998)

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:986)

  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatBase$FactoryWrapper.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatBase.java:36)

 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623) 

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626) 

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408) 

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 

   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 

  at es.user.Principal.onCreate(Principal.java:20) 

  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 

 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611) 

 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 

 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832) 

 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117) 

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935) 

   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 

   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 

 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Si revisas los mensajes en el LogCat te hará más fácil la vida al desarrollar aplicaciones Android. "Unable to start activity" te muestra el error en setContentView(R.layout.fragments); puede tener muchas causas...

Comment: He añadido los errores del LogCat que me indica. No entiendo muy bien donde estaría el error.

Comment: Excellent!!!! puedes ver que tienes un error más específico cuando  cargas la clase Principal y se trata de inflar el layout! : Principal}:   
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22:  En el archivo: layout/fragments.xml línea 22 se encuentra el problema.

Comment: Si, era eso. Tenía en esa linea añadido el fragmento que luego agregaba dinámicamente. Gracias :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El diseño normal es cargar un layout que debe contener un `FrameLayout` que sirve como "contenedor" y es donde se agregan o reemplazan fragmentos, por medio de [`FragmentTransaction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html), el layout se carga con :

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

donde `main_activity.xml` serîa :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/contenedor"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

En este caso, se tenía una referencia fija de un fragmento en el layout::

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
     ComponentInfo{es.user.prueba/es.user.Principal}:   
     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22:
     Error inflating class fragment
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
```